# Calling the setState hook within an async function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, react-state, react-effects

Im learning about how to call REST APIs from React and am confused about what happens when we call React within an async function.  In my component below, we see that in the first line of  `fetchPlaces` function, we are calling the `setIsFetching()` state to be true.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Places from "./Places.jsx";
import Error from "./Error.jsx";
import { sortPlacesByDistance } from "../loc.js";
import { fetchAvailablePlaces } from "../http.js";

export default function AvailablePlaces({ onSelectPlace }) {
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const [availablePlaces, setAvailablePlaces] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchPlaces() {
      setIsFetching(true);
      try {
        const availablePlaces = await fetchAvailablePlaces();
          setAvailablePlaces(sortedPlaces);
          setIsFetching(false);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setError({
          message:
            error.message || "Could not fetch places, please try again later.",
        });
        setIsFething(false);
      }
    }
    fetchPlaces();
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <Error title="An error occurred!" message={error.message} />;
  }

  return (
    <Places
      title="Available Places"
      places={availablePlaces}
      isLoading={isFetching}
      loadingText="Fetching place data..."
      fallbackText="No places available."
      onSelectPlace={onSelectPlace}
    />
  );
}
```

My question here is does React wait for the state to be updated until the whole function is completed? Or does it go and update the state then since its an async function and rerender the component again? If so, why?

Im guess Im confused because in other functions say for example:

```
 function a() {
    setIsFetching(true)
    // .... a lot more logic is done below 
}
```

doesn't React wait until after `a` is done running to update the state and re-render the component?  Why is it with the async function that the state is being updated before the function is running?  I would think it would wait for the whole function to execute since we have the await keyword

Comment: It waits until reaches "await" or ".then" , re-render and updates the state, and  then do it again when async is resolved or rejected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React will wait until your code yields control to the JS event loop before updating. Basically:

```js
async function fetchPlaces() {
  // no updates yet
  setIsFetching(true);
  // update is batched to be ran on the next rerender
  try {
    // by using `await` you are yielding control to the JS event loop.
    // code in this block will not run any more until `fetchAvailablePlaces` resolves.
    const availablePlaces = await fetchAvailablePlaces();
        // by here react will have updated the DOM
      setAvailablePlaces(sortedPlaces);
      // update is batched from the previous line
      setIsFetching(false);
      // this gets added to the batch
    });
  } catch (error) {
    setError({
      message:
        error.message || "Could not fetch places, please try again later.",
    });
    setIsFething(false);
  }
}
fetchPlaces();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! And im guessing when we end `fetchPlaces`, we then give up control to the event loop again thats when those two final state updates are made?

Comment: Yeah once react finishes the update, there will be no code running on the main thread, so JavaScript will go back to the next thing from the event loop which if your `await fetchAvailablePlaces()` has finished by then will probably be that code.